# S4 class from readr read_csv output

Tags: r, r-s4, readr

I wanted to create an S4 class which represents the data from a `read_csv` function call (`readr` package)

```
library(readr)
library(magrittr)

#data <- read_csv("random.csv")

data <- structure(list(id = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                              10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 
                              30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L),
                       value = c(0.711074015, 
                                0.614819585, 0.791768651, 0.385054413, 0.658395941, 0.204337366, 
                                  0.800191712, 0.049692407, 0.106693474, 0.989649574, 0.622873403, 
                                  0.269687142, 0.705086413, 0.520805849, 0.951492967, 0.63948476, 
                                  0.691096167, 0.284000329, 0.873882314, 0.48240776, 0.156761559, 
                                  0.149020867, 0.054223854, 0.429401826, 0.973400059, 0.030492575, 
                                  0.084345713, 0.538730795, 0.100815694, 0.443863626)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -30L), .Names = c("id","value"))

> head(data)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

     id     value
  (int)     (dbl)
1    10 0.7110740
2    10 0.6148196
3    10 0.7917687
4    10 0.3850544
5    10 0.6583959
6    10 0.2043374
```

I tried the following basic class setup

```
setClass(
      Class="RandomSample",
      slots=c(data="data.frame"),
      contains=c("data.frame")
    )


createContainer <- function(myData)
{
  return(new(Class = "RandomSample",data = myData))
}

containerBase <- createContainer(data)
```

which throws an error

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “RandomSample” object: 1: invalid object for slot "data" in class "RandomSample": got class "tbl_df", should be or extend class "data.frame"
invalid class “RandomSample” object: 2: invalid object for slot "data" in class "RandomSample": got class "tbl", should be or extend class "data.frame"
invalid class “RandomSample” object: 3: invalid object for slot "data" in class "RandomSample": got class "data.frame", should be or extend class "data.frame"
```

I realize that the object created by `read_csv` is not an S4 class and has three objects `data.frame` `tbl_df` and `tbl` where `tbl_df` is a function object for printing and `tbl` is a generic method as described in the help.

So how do I define the class `RandomSample` as an S4 class which represents the `read_csv` output object?

Comment: I don't get an error using your code, although your example isn't strictly reproducible because I don't know what your data are like.  BTW, the use of  representation in setClass is deprecated.

Comment: @David_B: Apologies, I realized a bit later that I forgot to add the reproducible data variable. I have edited the question now. Changing from `representation` to `slots` does not change the outcome though.

Comment: Still works fine for me.

Comment: @David_B: That's weird. If you execute `class(containerBase)` do you get the name of the class as RandomSample?

Comment: Yes, I do. ```class(containerBase)
[1] "RandomSample"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv```

Comment: @David_B Could this be due to different R versions? I have to check this on another machine. Mine is 

`> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132313/discussion-between-andrnev-and-david-b).

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by installing the latest version of the readr package (1.0.0). The read_csv function now adds additional attributes to the object which works when pulling into an S4 class. Don't fully understand why but learning slowly.